# Sum / subtotal visible cells based on cell or font color

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have a table that has a number of slicers attached. The table has conditional formatting that will change the font of a column on numbers to red or green depending on certain conditions.

I have seen a number of functions that count cells based on back ground color, but what I want to do is;

- subtotal only the visible cells in the range that are the same font colour as cell "R2"
- The sum is to be returned in cell "R2"
- Range is "M9:M200"
- I then need to have this run by slicer change as updating slicer will change all the figures.

I have found some code on here which I have tried to adapt and failed. Any help appreciated

I have been trying to convert the conditional formatting (red cells) to normal red with the below code, but thats not working either.

```
Sub GetColorSum2()
Dim FCELL As Range
    For Each rCell In Range("Y1:Y7").Cells
            If rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Then
                rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

MAIN CODE

```
Function GetColorsum(sumRange As Range, SumColor As Range, Optional VolatileParameter As Variant)
 Dim ColVal As Long, rCell As Range
 Dim Totalsum As Long
 ColVal = SumColor.Font.ColorIndex
    For Each rCell In sumRange.Cells
      If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = ColVal Then
          If rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
              If rCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
              Totalsum = Totalsum + 1
              End If
          End If
      End If
    Next rCell
 GetColorsum = Totalsum
End Function
```

I have also tried

```
Function Sumclr(rColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult
    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rCell, vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
    Sumclr = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: Colors resulting from use of CF are available only via the `DisplayFormat` property (eg `myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`) but if you're trying to use a UDF here then unfortunately `DisplayFormat` is not available in a UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to get a solution. Basically I did three things,

1. Replaced the function with a button.
2. Replaced the conditional formatting with VBA formatting.
3. summed the numbers using an IF hidden = false code

BUTTON

```
Sub CreateButton0()
  Dim btn As Button
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim t As Range
  Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 18), Cells(1, 18))
  Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
  
    With btn
      .OnAction = "SUMCOLOUR0"
      .Caption = "POPULATE"
      .Name = "Btn"
      .Font.Size = 8
    End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

FORMATTING

```
Sub HIGHLIGHT()
Dim FCELL As Range
        For Each FCELL In Range("M9:M1000").Cells
            If FCELL.Offset(0, 6) = "YES" Then
                FCELL.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                FCELL.Font.Bold = True
            End If
            If FCELL.Offset(0, -4) = "SR" Then
                FCELL.Font.ColorIndex = 10
                FCELL.Font.Bold = True
            End If
    Next FCELL
End Sub
```

SUMMING

```
Sub SUMCOLOUR0()
 Dim RCELL As Range
 Dim SCELL As Range
 Dim RRESULT As Double
 Dim SRESULT As Double
    ''''SUM OTE (RED)''''
    For Each RCELL In Range("M9:M1000").Cells
        If RCELL.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
          If RCELL.EntireRow.Hidden = False And RCELL.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
                RRESULT = WorksheetFunction.SUM(RCELL, RRESULT)
          End If
      End If
    Next RCELL
    Cells(2, ActiveSheet.Shapes("BTN").TopLeftCell.Column).Value = RRESULT
    
    ''''SUM SW (GREEN)''''
    For Each SCELL In Range("M9:M1000").Cells
        If SCELL.Font.ColorIndex = 10 Then
          If SCELL.EntireRow.Hidden = False And SCELL.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
                SRESULT = WorksheetFunction.SUM(SCELL, SRESULT)
          End If
      End If
    Next SCELL
    Cells(3, ActiveSheet.Shapes("BTN").TopLeftCell.Column).Value = SRESULT
End Sub
```